# Why is conformance to an object required for read/write extension properties to work on let variables?

Tags: swift

I know the title may be confusing, but this should clear it up.

Say I define the following extension on `UIView`...

```swift
extension UIView {

    var isVisible:Bool {
        get { return !isHidden }
        set { isHidden = !newValue }
    }
}
```

In code, I can do this without issue...

```swift
let myView = UIView()
myView.isVisible = true
```

But if I try pulling out the extension into a reusable protocol (so I can apply it to both `UIView` and `NSView` without having to duplicate the code) like so...

```swift
public protocol ExtendedView {
    var isHidden: Bool { get set }
}

public extension ExtendedView {

    var isVisible: Bool {
        get { return !isHidden }
        set { isHidden = !newValue }
    }
}

extension UIView: ExtendedView {}
extension NSView: ExtendedView {}
```

...then while I can read it like so...

```
let myView = UIView()

if myView.isVisible {
    ....
}
```

...This line will not compile!

```
myView.isVisible = true
```

It gives the following compile-time error...

```
cannot assign to property: 'myView' is a 'let' constant
```

To fix it, I have to either change the variable to a `var` (not what I want to do), or conform the protocol to `AnyObject`, like so...

```swift
public protocol ExtendedView : AnyObject {
    var isHidden: Bool { get set }
}
```

My question is why? I mean the compiler knows at compile time the type of item the extension is being applied to so why does the protocol have to conform to `AnyObject`? (Yes, I do acknowledge that extending `UIView` (or `NSView`) implies an object, but still... doesn't the call site know it's not a value type?)

Comment: This feels a little restrictive in this case, but in the more general case, the compiler is right. If you only had `let idkWhatTypeThisIs: any ExtendedView = ...`, and you wanted to call `idkWhatTypeThisIs.isHidden = true`, it's entirely possible that `idkWhatTypeThisIs` is a value type, which you've just allowed to mutate without it being explicitly allowed by the value type's definition.

Comment: As I’ve gone over below, thinking about reference vs. value of the entire type is not the issue. It’s only about the `mutating/nonmutating` nature of the property itself. Swift ingrains the idea that values and reference are tied to self-mutation via members, but it’s only the general case. You can get around it.

Answer (score 1):

> doesn't the call site know it's not a value type?

That doesn't matter. Protocol members allows for mutation of `self`. For example, if you don't constrain the protocol to `AnyObject`, this will always compile:

```swift
set { self = newValue as? Self ?? self }
```

I.e. protocols provide the only way to be able to change a reference internally. Even though you're not actually doing that in your code, the possibility of the reference mutation is there.

And even if you don't actually cause any mutation, property observers are still going to be triggered by mutating protocol members.

```
var myView = UIView() {
  didSet {
    print("Still the same \(myView) after `isVisible` changes, but that's not provable at compile-time.")
  }
}
```

---

Your particular issue is due to the default of `set` accessors.

```swift
{ get set }
```

is shorthand for

```swift
{ nonmutating get mutating set }
```

If you change the `get` to be mutating as well, you'll run into the same issue.

```swift
public protocol ExtendedView {
  var isHidden: Bool { get }
}

public extension ExtendedView {
  var isVisible: Bool {
    mutating get { !isHidden }
  }
}

// Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: 'myView' is a 'let' constant
let myView = UIView()
myView.isVisible
```

---

> I have to either change the variable to a var (not what I want to do), or conform the protocol to AnyObject

Although it's not apparent why you shouldn't be constraining to `AnyObject` or something more restrictive, you *can* just use

```swift
var isHidden: Bool { get nonmutating set }
```

That's enough to be able to make `myView` a constant. However, it's more accurate to mark `isVisible` completely nonmutating as well, which will stop property observers triggering.

```swift
nonmutating set { isHidden = !newValue }
```

---

Ultimately, constraining as much as possible is going to make working with any protocol easier. Especially when it allows you to enforce reference semantics.

```swift
public enum OldUIFramework { }

#if os(macOS)
import AppKit

public extension OldUIFramework {
  typealias View = NSView
}
#else
import UIKit

public extension OldUIFramework {
  typealias View = UIView
}
#endif

extension OldUIFramework.View: ExtendedView { }
```

```swift
public protocol ExtendedView: OldUIFramework.View {
  var isHidden: Bool { get set }
}
```

If you really need `ExtendedView` to apply to value types sometimes, then make a constrained extension for the other cases, calling the value type code.

*`any` should be `some`, here, but the compiler has bugs that make it not work right now.*

```swift
public extension ExtendedView where Self: OldUIFramework.View {
  var isVisible: Bool {
    get {
      let `self`: any ExtendedView = self
      return `self`.isVisible
    }
    nonmutating set {
      var `self`: any ExtendedView = self
      `self`.isVisible = newValue
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd never heard of `nonmutating`. But this looks like a misuse of it, because this setter _is_ mutating. It's not nice to lie to the compiler! :)

Comment: No, you guarantee that it’s nonmutating in the protocol definition. A value type could then be `ExtendedView`. It just wouldn’t be able to cause a mutation via `isHidden`.

Answer (score 0):

> I mean the compiler knows at compile time the type of item the extension is being applied to

I know, it *looks* like the compiler knows that, especially when you write the lines next to each other like that:

```
let myView = UIView()
myView.isVisible = true
```

But command-click on `isVisible` in that code, and where do you end up? In the protocol ExtendedView. In other words, `isVisible` is not ultimately a property declared by UIView; it's a property declared by ExtendedView.

And nothing about *the protocol itself* guarantees that the adopting object will be a reference type — unless *you* guarantee it by qualifying the protocol, either directly or in an extension of the protocol, by saying what kind of object *can* adopt it.

---

I would just like to add that the situation you've posited is extremely specialized: the issue only arises in exactly the situation you've created, where a protocol extension injects a computed property implementation into its adopters. That's not a common thing to do.